# How to add autocomplete feature in NSComboBox having NSAttributedStrings

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSTableView` with 5 columns. One of the column has `NSComboBoxCell`. This combo box is populated with number of strings in different different colors. So I used `NSAttributedStrings` to add colorful strings to my combo box. My problem is I want to add autocomplete feature to my `NSComboBoxCell`.

Earlier I did it for the combo box having all its members as `NSString` by subclassing `NSComboboxCell` and overriding completedString: method. How can I achieve the same for combo box with `NSAttributedString`?

Answer (score 0):

use the completedString: method only and use NSString. To change the color create a NSValueTransformer binding and use the code below. I hope it helps.
`

```
+ (Class)transformedValueClass{

    return [NSAttributedString class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation{

    return NO;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value{

    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSColor redColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil];

    NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:value attributes:attributes];

    return str;
}
```

Comment: 1. Is there any way to do it without the binding. Because I haven't used binding  in my code. 
2. Or If I use binding and do it as per your code do I need to use NSArrayController? 
3. Other thing is there are duplicate items in my combo box list. Whether autocompletion works with this kind of list (duplicate item) or not.

Comment: Use NSTableViewDataSourceDelegate methods:          numberOfRowsInTableView:
tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:
tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row: (cell-based tables only)

Comment: I am already using NSTableViewDataSourceDelegate methods as suggested by you. I have a NSTableView with 5 columns. One of the column has NSComboBoxCell. I am populating the combo box with name of files of different types (jpg, png) without their extensions. Different type of file in different color. I am using NSArray to store file names and to populate in combo box. Is it possible to add autocomplete feature for NSAttributedString without using the binding. Secondly there are duplicate items in combo box list. So whether autocomplete works with duplicate items or not? Please suggest....